# handle custom directive with ngFor - Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Yesterday I was trying to play with one of SO question and encountered problem within my solution.

in component's template, I'm using *ngFor* directive within which I'm using my custom `popover` directive. **Through directive only**, I want to show hide content for each *ngFor* object.

Once you check  http://plnkr.co/edit/X4U8ofJ5rgmE1YQ7fTAG?p=preview you will realize my problem.

on `mouseenter` event used within directive I want to show content of appropriate `ngFor` object.

**directive.ts**

```
import {Input,Component,Output,EventEmitter,Input,Directive,Hostbinding} from 'angular2/core';
import {Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '.tower-details',
    host:{
      '(mouseenter)':'show($event)',
      '(mouseout)':'hide()'
    }
})
export class popover{
   @Input() value: string;
   @Output() valueChange=new EventEmitter();


   ngOnChanges(...args:any[]){
     //console.log(args[0].value);
   }
   show(val)
   {
     console.log(val.target);
     this.valueChange.emit(true);
   }
   hide()
   {
     console.log('hide');
     this.valueChange.emit(false);
   }

}
```

**app.ts**

```
 template: `
    <div  *ngFor="#p of popovers;#index=index">
            <div class="tower-details"  [(value)]="show" style="display: block;border:1px solid green;background-color:orange" >
             Hover Me ! {{index}}
                <div *ngIf="show">
                <div class="popover top" style="display: block;border:1px solid green">
                    <h3 class="popover-title">{{p.title}}</h3>
                    <div class="popover-content">pop up content</div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
     </div>
  `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div  *ngFor="let p of popovers;let index=index">
            <div class="tower-details"  [(value)]="show[p.title]" style="display: block;border:1px solid green;background-color:orange" >
             Hover Me ! {{index}}
                <div *ngIf="show[p.title]">
                <div class="popover top" style="display: block;border:1px solid green">
                    <h3 class="popover-title">{{p.title}}</h3>
                    <div class="popover-content">pop up content</div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
     </div>
  `,
    directives: [popover]


})
export class App {

  popovers=[{"title":"popover1"},{"title":"popover2"},{"name":"title"}]
  show={'popover1': false, 'popover2': false, 'title': false};
}
```

The state for each item needs to be stored separately. If you use the same value for each, they show/hide synchronous.

Because you use two-way-binding on `[(value)]="show"` the value of each item will be propagated to to `App` and back to each `tower-details`.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wN157ZESOCllRCFWEuNG?p=preview)

**Update**

You can export a directive like:

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: '.tower-details',
    host:{
      '(mouseenter)':'show($event)',
      '(mouseout)':'hide()'
    },
    exportAs: 'tower'
})
export class popover{
```

then you can create a template variable to reference the value in the directive

```ts
        <div class="tower-details" #tower="tower" style="display: block;border:1px solid green;background-color:orange" >
         Hover Me ! {{index}} - {{tower.value}}
            <div *ngIf="tower.value">
```

You need to set the `value` in the directive as well instead of just emitting an event. In fact emitting an event is not necessary anymore except you want to bind for other means.

```ts
   show(val)
   {
     console.log(val.target);
     this.value = true;
     this.valueChange.emit(true);
   }
   hide()
   {
     console.log('hide');
     this.value = false;
     this.valueChange.emit(false);
   }
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/b0JZYUIXi1MSFVclPfcO?p=preview)

Comment: Gunter what If you don't have such boolean property and still you want to handle it through directive only.

Comment: here you know that you are having three objects, so you came up with three objects. But in reality what if there are thousand of objects within array. You simply can't go this way. right? I want some dynamic way. eg. use `index` and if we can do something with it using directive.

Comment: You could do it like in my first approach with any number of elements, it would need just minor code changes. I guess you'll like my 2nd approach better anyway.

Comment: 2nd approach is far better than 1 I guess. Simply super !

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the `show` variable you use is globally. You should use something like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="#p of popovers;#index=index">
        <div class="tower-details" (valueChange)="show[index]=$event" style="display: block;border:1px solid green;background-color:orange" >
         Hover Me ! {{index}}
            <div *ngIf="show[index]">
            <div class="popover top" style="display: block;border:1px solid green">
                <h3 class="popover-title">{{p.title}}</h3>
                <div class="popover-content">pop up content</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
  </div>
  {{show | json }}
`,
directives: [popover]
})
export class App {
  popovers=[{"title":"popover1"},{"title":"popover2"}, {"name":"title"}]
  show=[false,false,false];
}
```

See this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/pIgH4OdMIf7rj2NOw9b6?p=preview.

**Edit**

After thinking again, you could leverage the state of the applied directive directly to avoid the use of a `show` array.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.tower-details',
  host:{
    '(mouseenter)':'show($event)',
    '(mouseout)':'hide()'
  },
  exportAs: 'popover'
})
export class popover{
  shoudShow: false;

  show(val) {
    this.shoudShow = true;
  }

  hide() {
    this.shoudShow = false;
  }
}
```

And it this way in the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div  *ngFor="#p of popovers;#index=index">
        <div class="tower-details" #dir="popover" style="display: block;border:1px solid green;background-color:orange" >
         Hover Me ! {{index}}
            <div *ngIf="dir.shoudShow">
            <div class="popover top" style="display: block;border:1px solid green">
                <h3 class="popover-title">{{p.title}}</h3>
                <div class="popover-content">pop up content</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
   </div>
  `,
  directives: [popover]
})
export class App {
  popovers=[{"title":"popover1"},{"title":"popover2"}, {"name":"title"}]
}
```

See this new plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4Ewx15fYgm8AgejWZmXl?p=preview.

Comment: here you know that you are having three objects, so you came up with three objects. But in reality what if there are thousand of objects within array. You simply can't go this way. right? I want some dynamic way. eg. use `index` and if we can do something with it using directive.

Comment: In fact, arrays can be created dynamically of course. I thought to another solution ;-) I updated my answer accordingly...